# PHP function to handle most database queries has a problem with results. I am getting the right number of rows but they are all the same

Tags: php, mysqli

Here is my little function. It does not handle the results correctly. I do get all the rows that I want, but all the rows of the $results array contain the exact same values.

So i make 2 arrays, a temporary array to hold the values after each fetch, and another array to hold all the temporary arrays.

First i take the temp array and map its keys to the column names. Then i give it to bind_result, and call fetch() and use it like I would any other result value.

Could this be because I re-use the $results array?

numresults is the number of values you are taking from each row. if 0, you are not getting any results back.

```
function db_query($db, $query, $params = NULL, $numresults = 0)
{
    if($stmt = $db -> prepare($query))
    {
        if($params != NULL)
        {
            call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $params);
        }
        if(!$stmt -> execute())
        {
            //echo 'exec error:',$db->error;
            return false;
        }
        if($numresults > 0)
        {
            $results = array();
            $tmpresult = array();
            $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();
            while ($columnName = $meta->fetch_field())
                $tmpresult[] = &$results[$columnName->name];

            call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $tmpresult);       
            $meta->close(); 
            $results = array();
            while($stmt -> fetch())
                $results[] = $tmpresult;
        }
        $stmt -> close();
    }
    else
    {
        //echo 'prepare error: ',$db->error;
        return false;
    }
    if($numresults == 0)
        return true;
    return $results;
}
```

Comment: Could we see the query itself?

Comment: 'SELECT id, season, year, volume, number FROM issues'

it gives me the last row in the issues table with all its correct information 37 times (which is the number of rows in the issues table)

Answer (score 1):

You need to *copy* the values out of `$tmpresult` one element at a time.  Replace this:

```
$results[] = $tmpresult;
```

With this:

```
$tmpresultcopy = array();
foreach ($tmpresult as $key => $value) {
    $tmpresultcopy[$key] = $value;
}
$results[] = $tmpresultcopy
```

What you're doing now is just copying the references.  So you end up with `$results` storing N copies of the same set of references.

This is one of the reasons I recommend using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) instead of mysqli!  It's so much easier to use [`PDOStatement::fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

Comment: +1, faster typer then I am, References are only to be used if thoroughly understood, if even then :)

Comment: @Wrikken: And once you understand references, you don't want to use them.  :)